# Can I perform a SELECT within a WHERE in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to perform a select within a where clause.

Basically, I have a number of users, and trying to see which were active.  Active means they logged activity in last 30 days. But, if I join the user table with activity table, then I get duplicate user IDs (because each user may have logged multiple actions).

So I was looking at putting a select inside a where that would check, for each user, that there was at least one action.

```
SELECT u FROM `users` u
where (
select count(*) FROM `user_activity` ua
where ua.user_id = u.user_id and ua.last_login between "2012-04-01 00:00:00" and "2012-04-30 23:59:59"
) >= 1
```

Comment: so here question is what is the problem you are facing

Comment: shouldn't [distinct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u
FROM users u
where EXISTS ( select null
               FROM user_activity ua
               where ua.user_id = u.user_id
                 and ua.last_login between "2012-04-01 00:00:00" and "2012-04-30 23:59:59" 
               LIMIT 1)
```

Thanks to @Ami for pointing about about `LIMIT 1` in subquery that potentially could improve performance a bit

Comment: Would adding `LIMIT 1` to the correlated subquery make it perform better?

Comment: @zerkms Why do you capitalise `SELECT`, `LIMIT` and `FROM`  but not  `WHERE`, `AND` AND `BETWEEN`? Odd...

Comment: @Flukey: capitalized - is what I've written. Other parts are taken as is. Too bored to reformat the whole OP's query. PS: look at the original query in the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can nest a select inside a where clause like so:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE users in(SELECT users FROM  user_activity);
```

But I don't think you can nest an aggregate function like count(*) inside a where clause. So I would try this first and then the aggregate function, but try to write your select without the aggregate. I don't have you data in front of me so I can't help there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put a SELECT in a WHERE clause.

I would avoid the correlated subquery with a JOIN to see if it improved the performance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user`
FROM users u
JOIN user_activity ua
  ON ua.user_id = u.user_id
  AND ua.last_login BETWEEN '2012-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-04-30 23:59:59'
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` cannot be applied to the whole table, but `DISTINCT u.*` would work. PS: as long as OP wants only the users who had activity - `INNER JOIN` is what you wanted to write

Comment: The current query produces `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'u' in 'field list'`

Comment: @zerkms, thanks, I had caught the INNER JOIN. It's strange that we have a column `u` named the same as the table alias `u`, but MySQL didn't complain. The first `u` is the column.

Comment: oh, right, OP has `SELECT u` in the question but I bet he meant `u.*`